# Find an equation for the plane that contains the following line and passes through point P

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

How do you determine the plane which contains the line
\begin{align}
x & = -1 + 3t \\
y & = 5 + 2t \\
z & = 2 + t
\end{align}
and passes through the point $P = (2,4,-1)$?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way (it's always good to know more than one way to solve a problem).

Your plane goes through $(-1,5,2)$ and $(2,7,3)$ (obtained by taking $t=0$ and $t=1$, respectively) and also $(2,4,-1)$. If your plane is $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ then each of these three points gives you an equation relating the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$. So you get three homogeneous linear equations in 4 unknowns. Presumably, you know how to solve such a system. You'll get a one-parameter family of solutions (because $akx+bky+ckz+dk=0$ is the same plane, for any non-zero value of $k$); just pick any member of this family.

Comment: +1, this  is helpful. Also, a plane can be determined uniquely by three sets of points. An alternative way of solving the four unknowns is using the vector form.

Answer (score 2):

the line is
\begin{equation}
(-1,5,2) + t(3,2,1)
\end{equation}
Then the plane contains the segment
$\overline{(-1,5,2)(2,4,-1)}$ $\quad((-3,1,3) =  (-1,5,2) -((2,4,-1))$ and the plane $\Pi$ has normal $(3,2,1) \times (-3,1,3) = (5,-12,9)$. Hence the plane is $5x -12y + 9z + d = 0$. As $(2,4,-1) \in \Pi$, we have $d = 47$. Hence, the plane is
$5x -12y +9z +47=0$.

Comment: Does it make a difference if i get 3,-1,-3?

Comment: Not at all. All you need is any nonzero scalar multiple of the normal.